# Custom arrangement for fields with multiple values in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, entities

In Drupal 6 I used to make every sort of customised markup for CCK fields with multiple values. Usually this happened when I wanted to lay out thumnails for a gallery inside a table: I used to go into the relevant tpl.php file, grab the relevant $field_fieldname variable, loop through it, and print out the 'view' key for it, which contained the styled thumbnail, often linked to the original image and whatever.

Now, I'm a bit confused on how this should be done in Drupal 7. For now, I set up a suboptimal solution that goes like

```
<section class="gallery">
    <div class="row first">
    <?php foreach($content['field_gallery'] as $k => $v) : ?>
        <?php if(is_numeric($k)) : ?>
            <?php echo render($v) ?>
            <?php if((($k+1) % 4) == 0) : ?>
    </div><div class="row">
            <?php endif ?>
        <?php endif ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    </div>
</section>
```

but it's obviously wrong. I can't seem to get my head around this, even after having read lots of docs about the Field API and theming for D7. Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got an explanation on how [field_view_field](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.module/function/field_view_field/7) and rendering api for fields work in [this blog](http://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/rendering-drupal-7-fields-right-way).

Here you've got an example (extracted from the link above):

```
$node = node_load($nid);
$field = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_name');
$output = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_name', $field[$delta]);
```

You just need to loop over the $delta value for the fields to render them in a multiple valued field.

Comment: Yes, I've seen that blog post, and it seemed the most likely approach, though I think it's a bit out of context. I mean, in a template you should try not to call API functions, and this, unless done in some preprocess function, requires you to write a bit more code than it's necessary in the template itself. I was hoping in a more D6-ish solution, like at most calling render() on some render array.

Comment: Anyway, this seems to be the most flexible approach I've seen so far, so I'm accepting the answer :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ok, question: how do I configure it to work with Colorbox (and/or other lightbox plugins)? Using your third line, I get all the original images, not the thumbnails (and I've properly configure display settings in the Content Type settings). Using a display settings array things seem to get better, but I can't find what to use as image_link to make Colorbox pop up. Ideas?