# Render multiple values of a field in Drupal 7

Tags: entities, theming

I created a custom content type with a field with multiple values which I want to render as follows in my `node--custom_content.tpl.php`;

```
<div class="CLASS" style="background: url('<?php print file_create_url($node->field_creation_images['und'][0]['uri']);; ?>')"></div>
```

However, this renders only the first value of the field. Is there a foreach solution to my problem?

Comment: Please look at the code yourself. Especially at this `[0]` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multivalue field it makes the field value array like :

```
// $node->field_creation_images['und'][0]['uri'];
// $node->field_creation_images['und'][1]['uri'];
```

So to print all values you need to use foreach :

```
<?php foreach ($node->field_creation_images['und'] as $uri) { ?>
  <div class="CLASS" style="background: url('<?php print file_create_url($uri['uri']); ?>')"></div> 
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: Don't use raw data; try using the Drupal functions instead, like in http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15376/custom-arrangement-for-fields-with-multiple-values-in-drupal-7

Comment: this is not the correct answer as there are many issues with this (it won't even work on multi-lang site). Google "correct way to render fields in drupal" and click the first link.